# Minimal pom.xml for a Liftweb application

Tags: maven, lift

What is the most simple pom.xml file for a Liftweb application, using the latest released version available as of today -- 2011-01-15?

Comment: why don't you just download a blank lift 2.8.1 archetype and remove the obviously superfluous dependencies/plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doc using latest archetype:
http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Using_Maven

Answer (score 0):

I put together an updated set of instructions for using both Maven and Eclipse/Scala IDE (which has come a long way). See this answer:

[Setting up a Scala Lift project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112795/setting-up-a-scala-lift-project-in-eclipse/14765424#14765424)

or just visit:

https://github.com/awkay/lift_squeryl_demo